# three.js lookat() function not works as i need

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

there is my code
http://codepen.io/usf/pen/pGscf

in this part

```
 function animate() {   
   //sun.rotation.x = t/1000;
    sun.rotation.y += 0.01;

    t  += 0.1;
    earth.position.x = Math.sin((2*Math.PI/24*60*60)*timeScale*t)*300;
    earth.position.z = Math.cos((2*Math.PI/24*60*60)*timeScale*t)*200;

    camera.position.set(sun.position);
    camera.lookAt(earth.position);
    //sun.lookAt(earth.position);

    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);        
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate, renderer.domElement);
};
```

i want to look on earth from sun (lol), but i see nothing.
how can i fix that? I think there is some little mistake, but can't find it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong here: `camera.position.set(sun.position);`

The set method should be used like this :

```
set: function ( x, y, z ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;

    return this;
}
```

Use `camera.position.copy(sun.position)` instead.